# How to pass variable of one method in other method within the same class in Python

Tags: python, class, methods

I am taking an input `temp` from user in method `parameter` and I want to compare this `temp` with another variable `oven_temp` in the `make_item` method. But I get a `NameError`, saying that name `temp` is not defined.

I read some posts here and I understood that I need to `return` the value from the method - so I did that; but now what? Specifically, I tried:

```
class maker:
    def parameter(self):
        temp = int(input('At what temperature do you want to make \n'))
        return temp

    def make_item(self):
        def oven (self):
            oven_temp = 0
            while (oven_temp is not temp):
                oven_temp += 1
                print ("waiting for right oven temp")
        oven(self)

person = maker()
person.parameter()
person.make_item()
```

but I still get the `NameError`. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work to solve your problem.  Basically, you want to store the variables you want to pass between methods as members of the class.  You do this by assigning an attribute of the `self` parameter to the functions.

```
 class maker:
    def parameter(self):
        self.temp = int (input ('At what temperature do you want to make \n'))


    def make_item (self):
        def oven ():
            oven_temp = 0
            while (oven_temp is not self.temp):
                oven_temp += 1
                print ("waiting for right oven temp")

        oven()


person = maker ()
person.parameter()
person.make_item()
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep it in your`self`!

```
class MyMaker:
    def ask_temperature(self):
        self.temp = int(input('Temperature? \n'))

    def print_temperature(self):
       print("temp", self.temp)
```

Try it:

```
> maker = MyMaker()
> maker.ask_temperature()
Temperature?
4
> maker.print_temperature()
temp 4
```